# Перевод цвета в различные системы счисления

Tags: color

На собеседовании мне задали вопрос, который я меньше всего ожидал услышать, а именно: "Как перевести цвет из 16-ричной в 10-ричную систему счисления, сохранив при этом прозрачность, и наоборот?".
Например, такой формат `#ffffff` перевести в такой - `rgb(255, 255, 255)` или в `rgba`, если прозрачность присутствует.
**p.s.** собственно вопрос в кавычках.

Comment: Прозрачности ни в том ни в другом нет. В hex я видел в microsoft xaml так выглядит `#ffffffff` - тут первые 2 это прозрачность.

Comment: Это не конкретный пример, а мой, чтобы вопрос был понятней.

Comment: прозрачность есть в **rgba**, в **rgb** прозрачности нету.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`формат #ffffff перевести в такой - rgb(255, 255, 255)`

Учитываем, что каждая пара из шести символов в #ffffff представляет собой цвет RGB (red, green, blue), т.е. #ffffff -> #ff ff ff, затем каждый символ из шестнадцатиричного формата представляем в его двоичной форме, (значение для f = 1111), и получаем в итоге:

```
11111111 11111111 111111111
```

Затем переводим в десятичную систему каждое из трёх чисел, получая:

```
255 255 255
```

Аналогично с числовым отображением прозрачности, если она присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Задача не является специфической для цвета - если вы умеете переводить из 16-ричной системы в 10-ричную и наоборот, то сможете делать это хоть для цветов, хоть для чего угодно.

Это как таблица умножения - она одна, и нет отдельной таблицы, чтобы считать яблоки, отдельной чтобы считать окурки и т.п.

Такой формат - #ffffff является просто краткой формой для записи трёх 16-ричных чисел - (ff, ff, ff).
Если вы откроете любую программу-калькулятор, умеющую переводить между системами счисления, вы увидите, что ff и есть 255.

Если в цвете есть информация о прозрачности, то там будет ещё одно число.
В 16-ричной системе - ff, ff, ff, ff. То есть в краткой форме - #ffffffff